# How to update row and return id?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I use this function ORM to update row in table:

```
$client = Client::where("unique_code", $this->unique_code)->whereHas('types', function ($query) {
  $query->where("type", $this->type);
})->update(["status" => 1]);
```

How to return `id` of updated row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First what your using is not the ORM but the QueryBuilder.

You should assign the query result in a variable, process the update and then access the id.

```
$client = Client::where("unique_code", $this->unique_code)
  ->whereHas('types', function ($query) {
      $query->where("type", $this->type);
  })->first();

$client->update(["status" => 1]);
$client->id; // to get the id
```

Comment: that means no record has been found in your database with your where clause

Comment: You can prevent errors by checking if client is set before updating.

Comment: This is not working if there is multiple records. Do have any way around to get the ids without using another query!